# Class vectors - multiplication of two vectors of non-specific dimension

Tags: python, class, vector

```
class MyVector:
    def __init__(self, vector): # classic init 
        self.vector = vector 

    def get_vector(self):
        return self.vector

    def __mul__(self, other):
        for i in range(0, len(self.vector)): #cycle
           # if I did scalar_product += (self.vector[i] * other.vector[i]) here,
           # it didn't work
           scalar_product = (self.vector[i] * other.vector[i])
        return (scalar_product)    

if __name__ == "__main__":       #just testing program
    vec1 = MyVector([1, 2, 3, 4])
    vec2 = MyVector([4, 5, 6, 7])
    print(vec1.get_vector())
    print(vec2.get_vector())
    scalar_product = vec1*vec2
    print(scalar_product) # shows only 4*7 but not others
```

What do I have to do to make this program work? Now it just multiplies the last digits, for example 4 * 7, but not the other ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your scalar product first:

```
 def __mul__(self, other):
     scalar_product = 0 # or 0.0
     for i in range(0, len(self.vector)):
         scalar_product += self.vector[i] * other.vector[i]
     return scalar_product
```

You should also return an object of type `MyVector`

Comment: Now I feel so dumb :D